# Sending params and Json via HTTP POST

Tags: android, json, http, http-post

I need your help to understand this thing.
I have to make an http post request anche i have to send parameters and a very huge json array (data= [jsonarray]).
Now, if i have to send only paramters no problem..but i don't know how can i send also jsonarray.
How can i implement a part to send my jsonarray?
Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
public static String post(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams, JSONArray jsonArray) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        if (postDataParams != null) {
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
        }

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
        } else {
            response = "";

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "";
        String strParams = postDataParams != null ? postDataParams.toString() : "";
        IMLog.e(TAG, "Error....");
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your JSONArray to string using `toString()` method. After that you can add it to your HashMap like anyother parameters.

```
String jsonArrayString = jsonArrayObject.toString();
```

Where, `jsonArrayObject:` Your object containing the JSONArray.

Comment: Ok but if JSONArray is very huge? About 3600 items. Can i send as normal parameter of hashmap?

Comment: Yes. I don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: Thanks mate, sometimes i lost my self in a glass of water! :)

Comment: That's fine. Happy coding.. :)